# div gets hidden from other divs

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
   background-color: #191919;
 }
 .upperCircle {
   margin: 13% auto;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #F2AD43;
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
 
 .underRect {
   margin: -39% auto;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #F2AD43;
   border-radius: 15%;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
   .leftCircle {
   margin: 33.5% -50%;
   width: 160px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #E08027;
   border-radius: 50%;
   float: center;
 }
 
   .rightCircle {
   margin: 33.5% 33%;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: #824B20;
   border-radius: 50%;
   float: left;
 }
   .smallCircle {
   margin: 26.5% 30%;
   width: 40%;
   height: 40%;
   background: #FFF58F;
   border-radius: 50%;
   
 }
```

```html
<div class="upperCircle"></div>
<div class="underRect"><div class="rightCircle"></div><div class="leftCircle"></div><div class="smallCircle"></div></div>
```

I have a div which contains other divs. Now I want to display all those divs.
[Like this][1]

But it is like [this][2]
The small circle is on the right position. When I delete the other divs, then it appears.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/21PFX.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oHsr.png

```
<div class="upperCircle"></div>
<div class="underRect"><div class="rightCircle"></div><div class="leftCircle"></div><div class="smallCircle"></div></div>
<style>
 body {
   background-color: #191919;
 }
 .upperCircle {
   margin: 13% auto;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #F2AD43;
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
 
 .underRect {
   margin: -39% auto;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #F2AD43;
   border-radius: 15%;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
   .leftCircle {
   margin: 33.5% -50%;
   width: 160px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #E08027;
   border-radius: 50%;
   float: center;
 }
 
   .rightCircle {
   margin: 33.5% 33%;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: #824B20;
   border-radius: 50%;
   float: left;
 }
   .smallCircle {
   margin: 26.5% 30%;
   width: 40%;
   height: 40%;
   background: #FFF58F;
   border-radius: 50%;
   
 }
</style>
```

Comment: You can use z-index to make sure they overlap according to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a problem of element positioning.
Add position relative and z-index to your css like these:

```css
body {
   background-color: #191919;
 }
 .upperCircle {
   margin: 13% auto;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #F2AD43;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: relative;
   top: -30px;
 }
 
 .underRect {
   margin: -39% auto;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #F2AD43;
   border-radius: 15%;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
   .leftCircle {
   margin: 33.5% -50%;
   width: 160px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #E08027;
   border-radius: 50%;
   float: center;
   z-index: 3;
   position: relative;
 }
 
   .rightCircle {
   margin: 33.5% 33%;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: #824B20;
   border-radius: 50%;
   float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
 }
   .smallCircle {
   margin: 26.5% 30%;
   width: 40%;
   height: 40%;
   background: #FFF58F;
   border-radius: 50%;
   z-index: 2;
   position: relative;
   top: -210px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="upperCircle"></div>
<div class="underRect"><div class="rightCircle"></div><div class="leftCircle"></div><div class="smallCircle"></div></div>
```